# UICollectionView (UIScrollView) Not responding when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I've found a rather odd problem with my UICollectionView implementation in that when scrolling at a reasonable velocity releasing touch, and then while it is scrolling attempting to stop the scrolling doesn't work (By touching down).

Looking at my code, I can't understand what could have caused this, unless it's perhaps related to the subclass implementation of UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Any ideas of suggestions out there to debug and/or fix this?

Comment: How many cells are in the CollectionView ?

Comment: At least a thousand :)

Comment: Check the collectionView frame or user interations.

Comment: Why should the frame for the collectionview have anything to do with the touch events while the collectionview is scrolling at reasonably high velocity?

Comment: Can you share your code /

Comment: Provide some code, this question in not answerable in this state!